# AzCopy - .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I need to be able to use AzCopy on a computer that only has .NET 4.0 available. The only download link I have been able to find is http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy but this points to version 5.1.x which requires .NET 4.5. Does anyone know where I can get an older version or any other workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, Microsoft only provides latest version Azcopy. I search on Google, I could not find older version to download. If you could not upgrade your NET Framework 4.0 version. I suggest you could use [Azure CLI 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli-nodejs) or [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli) to manage Azure storage account. Azure cli does not require NET Framework.

> Azure CLI 2.0: Our next-generation CLI written in Python, for use with
>   the Resource Manager deployment model.
>
> Azure CLI 1.0: Our CLI written in Node.js, for use with both the
>   classic and Resource Managerdeployment models.

Update from comment:

I am using https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer and used py2exe to create a Windows executable I can call from a console app.

Comment: I figured it out, I am using https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer and used py2exe to create a Windows executable I can call from a console app.

Comment: @ansario Thanks for your share, I add it to my answer.